# How to overcome this error:Error in tapply(seq_len()

Tags: r, dataframe

I used the code below to get a linear regression prediction per row based on each species and it worked just fine:

```
R2 <- do.call("rbind", as.list( by(iris, iris["Species"], transform, regress=predict(lm(Sepal.Length~Sepal.Width + Petal.Length + Petal.Width,data=iris),newdata=iris,type='response')))
head(R2)
           Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width   Species  regress
setosa.1               5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2    setosa 5.021873
setosa.2               4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2    setosa 4.676855
setosa.3               4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2    setosa 4.745967
setosa.4               4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2    setosa 4.814754
setosa.5               5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2    setosa 5.090877
setosa.6               5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4    setosa 5.404108
```

However, when I tried to implement it on another data set where I would like to have the prediction based on country name (I can't upload it) i got the following error:

```
Error in tapply(seq_len(156695L), list(Country = c(72L, 168L, 207L, 94L,  : 
  arguments must have same length.
```

How can I solve this issue? Is there a better code that will do the job?

UPDATE:
I added two data frames to better explain my need:
I would like to have an `lm()` prediction per country as a new column for df1 based on the models per each country that should be based on data frame df.

```
    df <- read.table(text = "target birds    wolfs     Country
                                3        9         7 a
                                3        8         4 b
                                1        2         8 c
                                1        2         3 a
                                1        8         3 a
                                6        1         2 a
                                6        7         1 b
                                6        1         5 c   ",header = TRUE)
df1<-read.table(text = "target birds    wolfs     Country
                         6        4         5 a
                         4        5         3 a
                         3        8         2 a
                         1        6         4 b
                         3        5         1 a
                         2        2         1 b
                         9        9         4 b
                         8        9         5 c
                         2        3         1 c",header = TRUE)
```

So the result should be as below where country "a" prediction should be based on the lm() model for that country ony and so on..( fake numbers for the last column - it's only for the data frame's structure)

```
df1<-read.table(text = "target birds    wolfs     Country regress
                         6        4         5     a           5.2
                         4        5         3     a           5.4
                         3        8         2     a           4.8 
                         1        6         4     b           6.6 
                         3        5         1     a           5.0 
                         2        2         1     b           6.1
                         9        9         4     b           6.7
                         8        9         5     c           2.3
                         2        3         1     c           3.1 ",header = TRUE)
```

Comment: Without your data and code, it is unlikely that anyone will be able to tell you exactly why yoiu get that error message. But I can give you a hint. Most likely, the error happens in your call to the function `by`, since that function calls `tapply`, which is where the error occurs. The error message tells you that the arguments have incompatible length (try `by(iris, iris[["Species"]][-1], transform)` to reproduce the error message). Check that the number of rows in your first argument to `by` agrees with the length of the second argument.

Comment: And a little hint regarding coding style: The kind of long nested function call that you use is very hard to understand and very hard to type without errors. If you come back to code of that sort later, you might have a hard time figuring out your own code.

Comment: Thanks for your comments @Stibu, Regarding the first one, I use the same data frame for the prediction so I don't think that there should be any different number of rows between the two arguments.Regarding the second comment, I'll be happy to know how to make the code more firm and clear so any example is welcomed.

Comment: The error message tells you that it finds somewhere to objects that don't have the same length, even though they should. Try to use this information to find the error. Btw.: what is `sss`?

Comment: Hello @Stibu, I changed the "sss" as you wrote it's not very clear code.Is there a better function that can take into account the need to run the prediction upon each "Species" that I can use in order to evoid this error?

Comment: I used complete.cases() and also restricted the data set to 1:100 rows but still I get the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you can not give an example of data and code that actually reproduces your error, I can only guess what it is that goes wrong. But I think that I might have found the actual reason and so it is worth a try.

Unfortunately, it is also not entirely clear to me, what you want to achieve. This is mostly due to the fact that your code is not doing what (if I understand you correctly) you want to do. I think that you want to create an independent model for each `Species`, that is you want to create a linear fit that *only* includes the rows belonging to a given species. This is not what your code is doing. If your goal is something else, let me know. Parts of my answer might still be useful, though.

Let me first expalin to you what your code actually does. This will lead me to the reason for the error message and finally, I will explain how you can achieve the goal that I described above.

By using the function `by`, you make sure that `transform` is applied separately to the rows of `iris` that belong to a given species. However, when you build the model, you tell it to use *all the data* in `iris`. Thus, for each species, you will get exactly the same model and it will in all three cases be a fit to all the data. And the same problem occurs a second time: when you use predict, you tell the function to predict for *all the data* in `iris`. So, if you actually wanted an independent model for each species, this is not what you should do.

Now to the reason for the error message. As I mentioned, when you predict values, you create predictions for all the rows in `iris` and not just those with a given species. Now `iris` contains data for three species and for each one there are 50 rows. Your code produces for each species 150 (and not 50) prediction, because it predicts for all the 150 rows. Now R tries add these 150 values as a new column to a data frame that has only 50 rows. What R does in this situation is called recycling: it simply repeats the 50 rows three times and thus you get a data frame with 150 rows. (Read section 2.2 in https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.pdf, if this is new to you.) You can easily check that this is acutally happening by evaluating `nrow(R2)`. `R2` has 450 rows and not 150 as you probably expected.

So, why is there no error message for the example with `iris`, while you get an error in your example. This is where I can only guess. But I think the reason is this: recycling only works, if the vector can be repeated an integer number of times. In the case of iris this is possible, because you want to enlarge 50 rows to 150, which can be done by repeating the rows 3 times. If, however, in your actual code you have, say, 49 rows that have to be enlarged to 149, you will get an error because R can't do this. It is easy to recreate the error message with the `iris` example. Simply redefine `iris` by

```
iris <- iris[-1, ]
```

and run your example code again. You should get the familiar error message.

Now to the last point: how can you actually achieve your goal. The solution is to use `by` with a more complex, user-defined function:

```
predictions <- by(iris, iris[["Species"]], function(sdat) {
            model <- lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width + Petal.Length + Petal.Width, data = sdat)
            prediction <- predict(model, newdata = sdat)
            return (prediction)
})
```

For each call of the function, `sdat` will be a data frame that contains *only* the rows belonging to one of the species. Using this data frame for the `data` argument in `lm` will create a model with only this data, and using it in predict will predict only these data points. In order to add these results to `iris`, you could use

```
R2 <- transform(iris, regress = unlist(predictions))
```

To check the quality of your result, you could for instance plot the real value vs. the results of your model:

```
plot(R2$Sepal.Length, R2$regress)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Stibu really helpfull explanation that I'm sure will help others too.I do have 2 questions if I may: 1.where does the data source is defined (new data sdat)?
2.If I need to apply it on another data frame (same columns) where do I set the new data source? is it in the "prediction" line of code?

Comment: Look at the documentation of `by` and the `apply` family of functions. Basically, `by` applies the function defined as the third argument to each of the data frames that is produced from `iris` by splitting it up according to `iris[["Species"]]. That this new data frame is called `sdat` is due to the fact that I named the argument of the function like that. If you use another data frame, you will have to replace the first two arguments of `by` and you will have to rewrite the formula in `lm()`.

Comment: Thanks @Stibu, I meant that the prediction should be on a new data frame that sould be splitted like the train data frame.Consider iris for training and iris1 as the new data set.How can I implement the "Species" split so I'll be able to get the prediction per each "Species" on iris1?

Comment: I wrote : prediction <- predict(model, newdata = iris1) inside the function itself.Than iris1 <- transform(iris1, regress = unlist(predictions)) . Is it the right path?

Comment: Using `iris1` instead of `sdat` is simply a change of names, so it does not affect the result. Since you made quite an effort in your original code to hava a single data frame as a result (using `do.call` and `rbind`), I assumed this was the format you wanted. If you prefer to have three separate data frames, I can change the code accordingly. Just let me know.

Comment: Hello @Stibu, I do need the result as a single data frame.I intend to use the prediction on a new data frame that have the same columns and the same split by values ("Species") just other values for the other variables that are included in the lm() model.So I wonder how R knows to split the new data frame and attach the predictions values to the new data frame (iris1 for example) based on the new values.Any code example will be great..